# Unable to populate the List View with FirebaseListAdapter, just getting a blank screen

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to fetch the data from my Firebase Real Time Database and view it on the list view using the populateView method in FirebaseListAdapter but instead all I am getting is a blank screen. I'm a newbie.

The Main Activity

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.format.DateFormat;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

    public class ViewOrder extends AppCompatActivity {
        FirebaseListAdapter<MakeOrder> adapter;

        ListView listoforders;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_order);
            listoforders = findViewById(R.id.lv);

            Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("order");
            FirebaseListOptions<MakeOrder> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<MakeOrder>()
                    .setQuery(query, MakeOrder.class)
                    .setLayout(R.layout.list3)
                    .build();

            adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<MakeOrder>(options){
                @Override
                protected void populateView(View v, MakeOrder model, int position) {

                    TextView tvTable = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvtable);
                    TextView tvOrder = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvorder);
                    TextView tvPrice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);
                    TextView tvTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvtime);

                    tvTable.setText(model.getOrderUser());
                    tvOrder.setText(model.getOrderText());
                    tvPrice.setText(model.getOrderPrice());
                    tvTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", model.getOrderTime()));
                }
            };
            listoforders.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

ListView Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewOrder">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Custom List Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvtable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Table" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvorder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Order" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvprice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Price" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvtime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Time" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Gradle:App

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.smartrestaurant"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:+'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Gradle:Project

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: What is the in the logs?

Comment: Do you have any errors? Have you tried to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`, as the last line in your Gradle:App file? Please also respond with @AlexMamo